# Custom customer attribute possibly affecting Customer Login

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have the following custom attribute that is used on the Customer object in Magento 1.7, for some reason while it creates the corresponding column(s) I can no longer login to the frontend of the Magento site (the backend works fine).

When I attempt to login it basically redirects back to the page but I am not logged in

Can anyone suggest what with in the following installer script(s) will be preventing me from logging into the site?

```
$installer->addAttribute("customer", "organisation_id",  array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Organisation ID",
    "input"    => "int",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => false,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""
));


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "is_school",  array(
    "type"     => "tinyint",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Is School?",
    "input"    => "int",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => false,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""
));

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "organisation_name",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Organisation Name",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => false,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""
));
```

Comment: Did you try debugging `Customer/controllers/accountController/loginAction` function?

Comment: Should I just edit the core file e.g var_dump($var)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point. if you mean "how to debug?", you can debug by using method like `Mage::log($var)`.. this will log in `var/log/system.log` file. please ignore if you already know this.

Comment: BTW, I think the problem is happening because of empty string in `default` property. It is just a hunch. :)

Comment: i'll try null and see what happens in the default property

Comment: Tried setting the default value to NULL but i am still seemingly unable to login although i'm guessing the problem is related to these installer scripts on the customer object - is there a good resource for Magento installer scripts/options

Comment: Use this on login.phtml file <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>

Comment: I've put that <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?> code in my persistent/customer/form/login.phtml and cannot seem to see anything different when i reload the page... any other ideas guys i'm at a bit of loss

Comment: @Zabs: I know you are using Magento 1.7 but try this out...http://blueclawecommerce.co.uk/blog/fix-customer-cannot-login-to-magento-1-8-1/ ...tell me one thing.if you remove your custom attribute then login is working or not ?

Comment: @Zabs Not sure what could be the problem but keep `null` there instead of empty string. also try debugging accountController file as I mentioned in above comments.

Comment: Might be slightly off-topic... but would I need to add the fieldsets for each one of these new customer attributes in my module config.xml file? e.g organisation_id, organisation_name & is_school columns

Comment: @VishalSharma the blueclaw url looked good but unfortunately didnt help me in this instance..